# What's the difference between using the Disguise skill and the Fabricate Disguise spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, skills, disguise

The [Fabricate Disguise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fabricate-disguise) spell basically creates a non-magical disguise in an instant (1 standard action) and allows the caster to make a Disguise skill check to determine how effective it was. It uses materials the caster already has available.

The [Disguise skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/disguise) takes (1d3 × 10) minutes of time to create.

Is there any difference between the two besides the time required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Fabricate Disguise simply allows you to use a 1st level spell slot to forgo the 10-30 minutes it would normally take to change your appearance.

This seems like a reasonable use of a spell slot, being that it doesn't give you any particular bonus to the check. It would be very situational if it became useful- you'd have to have less than the normal amount of time to make a disguise (which most people would have prepared ahead of time).

Comment: It's useful because it's instantaneous and mundane: no magic aura to detect and no illusion for *true seeing* to penetrate!

Comment: Also a good point.

Comment: Great for when you are running away from the guards and go around the corner. 1 quick cast and you just stroll away free.